# StyleCop rule for different bracing style instead of just disabling it?

Tags: c#, coding-style, stylecop, curly-braces

**1st**, lets be clear that [bracing style is mostly taste only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624286/does-anyone-change-the-visual-studio-default-bracing-style-in-c-sharp-is-there) - that is, if a team decides on a certain taste, who am I to question that (within reason).

The problem is then when you use tools like StyleCop (btw. are there actually any other C# tools like StyleCop? I have the impression its rather singular in the C# ecosystem?)

StyleCop, by default, enforces a certain bracing style, the one in question I found is: [`CurlyBracketsForMultiLineStatementsMustNotShareLine`](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1500.html), i.e. it enforces

```
void bla()
{
  return x;
}
```

instead of

```
void bla() {
  return x;
}
```

The team, however, would *really* like to stick to the second style.

The question I ask myself is now:

- **Can I get Stylecop to validate the other rule, instead of [just disabling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/643403/321013) the rule?**
- Are we shooting ourselves in the foot by deviating from the StyleCop recommendation?

Comment: Not supported, according to [this Stylecop issue](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/6693).  I couldn't find a K&R ruleset after a brief Google, but maybe it's out there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863059/stylecop-rule-for-different-bracing-style-instead-of-just-disabling-it?noredirect=1#comment42291279_26863059):

The style referred to in the question is mostly [K&R indentation style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) and there is a [StyleCop issue 6693](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/6693) that is closed with the message:

> Closed Aug 17, 2010 at 11:17 PM by jasonall
>
> StyleCop does not comply
> with the K&R style. It would be difficult to tweak the rules to
> partially support this style. A better option would be for a
> third-party dev to create an alternate K&R ruleset.

So it is simply not supported.